# List Permissions of a user in CosmosDB using SDK

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-rest-api

I am trying to do a POC on **[List Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/list-permissions)** of a local user in **CosmosDB**.

I am referring to this Doc for [List permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/list-permissions).

Can someone give me a sample code to run below REST API (using primary Key)

> https://mynosqlaccount.documents.azure.com/dbs/MyDatabaseID/users/VinnyG/permissions

I am trying to use below sample code but it continuously fails no matter what i try. Can someone correct me what I am missing?

```html
string AccessToken = GenerateMasterKeyAuthorizationSignature(HttpMethod.Get, ResourceType.RegistryKey, "dbs", "Fri, 30 Dec 2022 22:08:00 GMT", "MyPrimaryKey from Cosmos DB Account");

var httpClient = new HttpClient
  {
      BaseAddress = new Uri("https://my-nosql-account.documents.azure.com/")
  };
string endpointUrl = "dbs/CosmosDBSql1/users/VinnyG/permissions";
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, endpointUrl);
request.Headers.Add("authorization", AccessToken);
request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2018-09-17");
request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", "Fri, 30 Dec 2022 22:08:00 GMT");
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Error Message:

> "code":"Unauthorized","message":"The input authorization token can't serve the request. The wrong key is being used or the expected payload is not built as per the protocol. For more info: https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-tsg-unauthorized. Server used the following payload to sign: 'get\npermissions\ndbs/CosmosDBSql1/users/VinnyG\nfri, 30 dec 2022 22:08:00 gmt\n\n'\r\n

Answer (score 0):

That API call is for permissions granted to users who login using [resource tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data?tabs=using-primary-key#resource-tokens), not the newer [RBAC permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac#permission-model). To access those permissions you need to call the Cosmos resource provider for [GET SQL Role Assignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/cosmos-db-resource-provider/2022-05-15/sqlresources2/get-sql-role-assignment?tabs=HTTP#sqlroleassignmentgetresults)